# Running compiled file issue - eh_frame_hdr

Tags: android, android-ndk

I compiled simple file `main.cpp` using `android-ndk-r8b`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I used command as follow:

> .../android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build APP_ABI=x86

from the directory of main.cpp file
My Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fPIC
LOCAL_MODULE := main
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Then I tried to open this file on debian x86 and I have this information:

> ./main: No such file or directory

then I used command:

> ld main

and had information:

> ld: error in main(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
>   ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008048320

Is it possible to run file compiled via android-ndk on a common linux x86 distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Android run-time libraries are not compatible with desktop Linux.

Note that your ndk-build puts the **main** executable in **./libs/x86/**